# Joining by closest timestamp in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have two large tables in a Presto - `calls` and `mobile_updates`.  Each `mobile_id` has multiple updates, each with a new software `version`.
Each call was made at a fixed timestamp `call_started`.

My objective is join the two by the closest (previous) `created_at` timestamp in `mobile_updates` to when the call was made, and by `mobile_id` to get the `version` at the time the call was made in Presto.  The result should be two columns: `call_started` and `version`

The existing code for some reason does not produce the desired results - it only returns the most recent call for each `mobile_id`, whereas there should be multiple calls.

Subqueries are not supported in Presto, so that is why partitions must be used.  What could be wrong?

```
with calls as (

SELECT  
      call_started
    , mobile_id
from calls
)

, ranking as (
select 
    mu.mobile_id
    , mu.version
    , mu.created_at
    , c.call_started
    , rank() over (partition by mu.mobile_id order by mu.created_at desc) as rank 

from mobile_updates mu
join calls c
    on mu.mobile_id = c.mobile_id 
where mu.created_at < c.call_started
) 

select 
    call_started
    ,version
from ranking 
where rank = 1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Subqueries are not supported in Presto"?
I know many TPC-DS queries include complex subqueries and Presto is able to execute all of them.
Could you please show us a subquery that did not work for you?
Also, what's the version of Presto you are using?